# Can't browse & access hidden Files and Folders with chromium

Tags: 20.04, permissions, chromium, hidden-files

One HTML page of mine needs to access images that are stored in a hidden folder .local/ in order to render them and generate PDFs.

However when I try to access any files stored in an hidden folder I get a "Access to the file was denied" error. I can't open those folder in Chromium neither.

I tried to check the permissions with ls -al but it doesn't seem to be helpful, here for instance the folder .anaconda has more permissions than the folder anaconda3 but still Chromium can browse anaconda3 but not .anaconda

```
drwxrwxr-x 1 jb   jb        18 Dec 30  2017  .anaconda
drwxr-xr-x 1 jb   jb       364 Jan 23  2020  anaconda3
```

My ubuntu version is: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
My Chromium version is: 88.0.4324.96

Any idea how I could figure this out?

EDIT1: I just created two folders with the following commands

```
mkdir thisisatest
mkdir .thisisatest
```

As expected Chromium can access the first one but not the second one which is hidden :/

EDIT2: I tried with another computer (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), It works without any problem (I can browse any given hidden folder). Still trying to understand what is going on here.

EDIT3: Just tried with Firefox and Firefox can browse hidden Folders & files.